# how to release memory of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a server that saves 1000 record every minute, I wrote a trigger that does a series of jobs for every row and I used a lot of table and other variables in it. Now my SQL Server memory usage increases very fast and I can't manage it.
I set min server memory and max server memory but it can't help me, when I set max memory server my SQL Server performance decreased and save process interrupted.
I used these resources but these can't help me:
[Great SQL Server Debates: Lock Pages in Memory](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/great-sql-server-debates-lock-pages-in-memory/)
[How to: Set a Fixed Amount of Memory (SQL Server Management)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191144%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) 
I have to reset SQL Server Service every 4 hour but this is not a correct way.
How to release memory of SQL Server?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? SQL Server uses as much memory as it does because it uses it to cache data to avoid having to go to disk. When you constrain memory unnecessarily, you make it have to go to disk to fetch the results again. And restarting the instance is a form of constraining.

Comment: yes, it is but I need another way to constrain SQL Server to release memory.

Comment: You didn't answer the question: what problem are you trying to solve? High memory usage isn't a problem.

Comment: my memory is limited to 16G  and I have to release memory.

Comment: Unless you're running something else on the box (eg iis), that's not a problem. I can't imagine your app performance is great after a server bounce while you're waiting for the cache to repopulate. If it's really bothering you that much set MSc server memory and be done with it. If you don't have enough memory in the box, use data to prove it to your manager.